# Need to clear contents of cell given first three letters

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple columns in my worksheet. In one particular column, several things can happen. The cell can start with "Ref", "FFC", or be blank entirely. I need the code to clear the contents of the cell if the cell starts with "Ref". Here is what I have so far.

```
Sub test()
    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With Range("E1", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter 1, "Ref*"
            On Error Resume Next
            .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.ClearContents
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With`enter code here`
End Sub
```

This method works well at identifying the cells in column E that start with "Ref*" but the .EntireRow.ClearContents does exactly that when I really only need it done for the cells in column E that fit the "Ref*"

I'm not sure if I should be using some sort of "If Len() Then" type of statement. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What happens if you remove the `.EntireRow` bit from that line of code?

Comment: just offset(1).clearcontents should do

Comment: Wow my newness is showing! you guys fixed it immediately. Thanks!!